# Add a route to manage multipage content

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need your help.
I have a small CMS, and my CMS serves articles, news and reviews.
At this moment I have single page content, but now I want to add multipage feature. 
It looks easy but it's not, and now I will try to show you how I manage my content.

My content Class

```
class Content < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :elements, class_name: 'ContentElement'
end
```

My News class

```
class News < Content
  def main_image_class
    'news'
  end
end
```

My Review class

```
class Review < Content

end
```

I choose this design pattern when I create the CMS because I plan to add several type of contents with several layout views, so I create a generic content and some subclasses.

As you can see the content class has many "ContentElement": when I design my CMS I have in mind the multipage feature, so instead of having a "body" in content I generate a ContentElement with this schema:

```
  create_table "content_elements", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.text     "body"
    t.string   "type"
    t.integer  "content_id"
    t.integer  "position",   default: 0
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.text     "meta_body"
  end
```

The content element can be "text" type, video, images, everything.

The "body" of the first ContentElement associated to my content is by the way the "body" of the content I render in my view. Single page, of course, because now for every content I can add just one ContentElement.

Add the multipage feature might look easy: I add a class if I need to override some generic methods and I generate more ContentElement for every content and the first ContentElement is the first page, others are the second, third, etc...

```
class MultipageContent < Content

end
```

My issue is related to the "routes".
Now I use this route to generate my url for a single page content:

```
  match '/magazine/:id/:permalink' => 'contents#show', via: :get, as: :content
  # http://www.example.com/magazine/11856/This-is-my-content
```

I need to keep this structure for every single page content, but I also need to adapt the same structure for a multipage content. So I have to find a way to generate a route like this:

For a single page content is the same:

```
# http://www.example.com/magazine/11856/This-is-my-content
match '/magazine/:id/:permalink' => 'contents#show', via: :get, as: :content
```

For the first page of a multipage content is the same:

```
# http://www.example.com/magazine/11856/This-is-my-content
match '/magazine/:id/:permalink' => 'contents#show', via: :get, as: :content
```

For the second, the third... page of the multipage content I have to obtain a match like this:

```
# http://www.example.com/magazine/11856/This-is-my-content-title/this-is-the-second-page
```

`This-is-my-content` is the slugged title of the "Content" class element, while `this-is-the-second-page` is the slugged name of the corrisponding ContentElement

I can also accept something like this, a unique route

```
# http://www.example.com/magazine/11856/This-is-my-content-title/this-is-the-content-element-name
```

but with this route **must work just with instances of the MultipageContent class**, for other typo of contents the route cannot be modified.

Can you help me?

Comment: I guess parantheses should do the trick `match '/magazine/:id/:permalink(/:addl_permalink)' => 'contents#show', via: :get, as: :content` . This way, if you send the addl_permalink you would get that second or third page or else the first page. Parantheses is understood as optional by rails routes.

Comment: For each page of multipage content do you have a record in db? In that case you should be adding that in route as well for readability. Like, `match '/magazine/:id/:permalink(/:sub_page_id/:addl_permalink)' => 'contents#show', via: :get, as: :content`

Comment: @VamsiKrishna thank you so much. Looks easy so. Add reply!

Comment: Glad that I could be of help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess parantheses should do the trick.

```
match '/magazine/:id/:permalink(/:addl_permalink)' => 'contents#show', via: :get, as: :content
```

This way, if you send the addl_permalink you would get that second or third page or else the first page. Parantheses is understood as optional by rails routes.

For each page of multipage content do you have a record in db? In that case you should be adding that in route as well for readability. Like,

```
match '/magazine/:id/:permalink(/:sub_page_id/:addl_permalink)' => 'contents#show', via: :get, as: :content
```

Comment: what happens if I use these routes?

`match '/magazine/:id/:permalink' => 'contents#show', via: :get, as: :content`
`match '/magazine/:id/:permalink/add_params' => 'contents#multipage_show', via: :get, as: :content`

I want to render another view on multipage

Comment: You can do that if the view is gonna differ. But, I would change the multipage_show to be `as: :multipage_content` :)